# Database design for same site for different clients

Tags: database-design

What if I'm going to build a site which is going to be used and maintained by multiple clients. The clients only have access to their own data. And I almost never have to access the data myself. It's a totally different website, but it's going to be something like [GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/) the way it is going to be setup. E.g. the clients will have the control over their own 'community'.

Will I setup 1 database with all the communities in it with access control or should every community have their own database?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a single database, but you associate each record with a community. Which means that each community will always see data that belongs to them.

The challenge with each community having their own database comes with difficulty in deploying application updates, resource usage and monitoring.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx for more information on how to deal with multi-tenant databases